# How to build an advanced search form for the search api

Tags: 7, search

I have custom content types that represent documents stored in Drupal; each content type has different fields but also some in common like:

- title
- language
- date
- attached text

I am currently using the Search API and Solr to index them.

I 'd like to create a search page like those created by the `Search pages` module that has two versions:

- A simple search form with one search box that searches the attachment content and returns highlighted search results
- An advanced form that includes extra search boxes e.g. for title, and date

I know how to do the advanced form with Views, but I am not totally satisfied with the fulltext search exposed field.

Could someone guide on which steps to follow?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Requests for tutorials are off-topic, here; I removed that part from the question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just wanted to ask for some general advice and sometimes answers include links to tutorials ;)